# google cloud storage transfer tls minimum version

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-storage, tls1.2

We have a number of google cloud storage transfer job that sync from aws s3 buckets to google buckets.  I am assuming that they are using https to transfer the data but where can I get a confirmation that they do.  Where can I get information about minimum TLS version used in these transfer jobs.

Comment: Here is a lot of info on how Google uses encryption to protect your data: https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-in-transit/ - maybe there's something in there that answers your questions/concerns. (I did not read it all)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Cloud Storage TLS, [in this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/SecurityandPrivacyConsiderations#transport-layer-security) you could find the TLS information for the gsutil commands which requests are done via the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil#syntax). These requests are via HTTPS only, and are used within the cloud console too.